# Checking if writeFileSync successfully wrote the file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple route defined with `express.js`:

```
exports.save = function (request, response)
{
    var file = request.body.file;
    var content = request.body.content;

    var saved = false;

    if (fs.existsSync( file ))
    {
        saved = fs.writeFileSync(file, content, 'utf8');
    }

    console.log( saved ); // undefined or false, never true

    response.send(saved ? 200 : 500, saved ? 'saved' : 'error'); // 500, error
};
```

Is `if (typeof saved === 'undefined') saved = true;` the only option? Feels hacky.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

According to node.js [source-code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js) [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L941) doesn't return anything.

It throws an `Error` object if something goes wrong. So you should write `fs.writeFileSync(file, content, 'utf8');` within a `try-catch` block.

Comment: My code is not throwing any error, and even it is not creating file. fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+"./../BusinessNames/currentDB.txt", 'nul.vyp'); . Not creating file because nul is reserved keyword in windows

Comment: my code is generating error: undefined but the file is created correctly. the error is completely superfluous..

Answer (score 12):

fs.writeFileSync does not return any value, if there is no exception happens that means the save succeeded; otherwise failed.

you may want to try the async version of file read

```
fs.exists(file, function (exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.writeFiles(file, content, 'utf-8', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        response.send("failed to save");
      } else {
        response.send("succeeded in saving");
      }
  } else {
    console.log('file does not exists');
  }
}
```

Comment: The async version doesn't go well together with HTTP responses, that's why I'm going the sync way.

Comment: I was skipping the 3rd parameters... :(

Comment: @jolt I know I'm late to the party but I don't see anything wrong with using them with HTTP requests. All you need to do is do the other operation in the "success" callback.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 fs.exists(file, function (exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.writeFiles(file, content,  err=> {
      if (err)   res.status(500).send({error: "failed to save"});
       else    res.status(200).send({message : "succeeded in saving"});
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({error: "file not exists"})
  }
}
```

Use async instead of sync. This will work.