# NWJS can't re-save file

Tags: node.js, fs, nwjs

I have nwjs app, and i want save file. So I have code like this:

```
try {
    fs.writeFileSync(this.value, data);
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

and it's good. But when I want re-save data in the same file, it's not working. No error but no new data in file to.

Answer (score 2):

You should refer this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html).

Try below code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hello!", function(e) {
    if(e) {
        return console.log(e);
    }

    console.log("The file is saved!");
});
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15543673/4198099) will be useful too :)

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an input like `<input type="file" nwsaveas="myFile.txt">` and can't re-save file because of this issue:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/file-dialogs#choosing-the-same-directory-multiple-times

To solve it I reset the input value to empty string after fs.writeFile().